# Single word for "divine healing" or "spirit healing"?

Tags: single-word-requests

I need a single word which can represent below phrases or meanings:

> Divine healing
>   Spirit healing

like there are phrases for *Long journey* i.e.  *Voyage*.

Comment: Hi, you may want to visit http://ell.stackexchange.com - I could not find any one word synonyms here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faith_healing

Comment: Worth noting though that "faith healing" seems to be in more common usage than either of the examples in the question, although not a single word.

Comment: @mplungjan how is this suited to ell?

Comment: Not the question but the level of English exhibited by OP

Answer (score 3):

I think the term 'healing' on its own can and does connote spiritual healing.

In mainstream medicine the word 'healing', where it is used, is employed in specific contexts e.g. 'The healing process is longer in the case of X than of Y'. We do not talk of someone going to hospital to be 'healed'. We talk of them needing 'treatment', or a surgical procedure' or the like.

So it may well be possible simply to use 'healing' and rely on the context to confirm that it is spiritual healing of which you are speaking. But why not, for clarity's sake simply say 'spiritual healing'?

Answer (score 1):

The closest word I've found so far is

> **theotherapy**: treatment of illness or disease by prayer and other
>   religious exercises

as defined [here](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/theotherapy).

Comment: thanks dear...am looking for more easy and effective word for this.....pls sugget some more matchings...

Comment: I'd be very surprised if there are any "easier" single words. WS2's answer is very good and I would also suggest that you will lose clarity if you use anything shorter than "spiritual healing" and "divine healing".